# Problem with using ajax in visual studio

Tags: asp.net, ajax, visual-studio-2010

```
<cc1:Rating ID="Rating1" runat="server"
    MaxRating="5"
        CurrentRating="2"
        CssClass="ratingStar"
        StarCssClass="ratingItem"
        WaitingStarCssClass="Saved"
        FilledStarCssClass="Filled"
        EmptyStarCssClass="Empty"
>
            </cc1:Rating>
    </asp:Content>
```

That rating control doesnt appear on the page!!

```
    <%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/YourGuruMaster.master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="PickTheBestAnswer.aspx.cs" Inherits="PickTheBestAnswer" %>
<%@ Register assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" tagprefix="cc1" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" Runat="Server">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder2" Runat="Server">

   <asp:PlaceHolder ID="PlaceHolder1" runat="server"></asp:PlaceHolder>

<cc1:Rating ID="Rating1" runat="server"
    MaxRating="5"
        CurrentRating="2"
        CssClass="ratingStar"
        StarCssClass="ratingItem"
        WaitingStarCssClass="Saved"
        FilledStarCssClass="Filled"
        EmptyStarCssClass="Empty"
>
            </cc1:Rating>



    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Height="71px" Width="231px"></asp:TextBox>



</asp:Content>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The namespace should be `AjaxControlToolkit` and not `AjaxControlToolkit.HTMLEditor`

Comment: Now I dont see the error, but i dont get the control on the page.. see answer updated!!

Comment: What is the css for the classes `ratingStar`, `ratingItem`, `Saved`, `Filled` and `Empty`?

Comment: I dont know... i copied the class as it is from an example i found on the net

Comment: As you need to log in to download that, I don't have access. The CSS needs to have a background image for each of them classes and the image needs to be a valid url. Surely if you downloaded the source it has some css in it. If you have left out the css then that is your problem.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Ajax Control Toolkit .NET 3.5 with Visual studio 2008, you must have installed  Visual Studio Service Pack 1 . I think it is your issue. Follow instructions which are given bellow, refer the "Note" part in that.

http://ajaxcontroltoolkit.codeplex.com/releases/view/90063